# Is "where to find RAW files" a good question?

Tags: discussion, off-topic, questions

We have an old (2012) question "[Where can I get free RAW files online for practicing with Lightroom?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/25413/where-can-i-get-free-raw-files-online-for-practicing-with-lightroom)". To me, this is showing many of the problems of off-site resource questions:

- In the top-voted, accepted answer (Fro Knows Photo), it's really not clear to me where to get RAW files.
- The second answer ("Free Practice & Portfolio Building RAW Image Files For Retouchers") doesn't have any RAW files available
- RETOUCHBOX doesn't seem to have any free RAW files any more.

I suspect this question would get closed pretty sharpish if it were posted today. Should we close or lock this one?

Comment: Although this one isn't community wiki, I think a lot of [How should we handle community wiki pages which are a big mess?](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1833/how-should-we-handle-community-wiki-pages-which-are-a-big-mess) applies.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's a poor fit. Basically:

1. It's a list oriented question and such questions tend to be poorly maintained. Ideally we would want to be able to have questions, along with their answers, stand the test of time as much as possible.
2. Will suffer from link rot. Given that the effective answers are essentially links, there is a high risk that many will become dead in time.